# Why go plugin addresses does not load with go binary

Tags: go

I created a plugin using https://github.com/vladimirvivien/go-plugin-example

```sh
go build -buildmode=plugin -o eng/eng.so eng/greeter.go
```

Created a go binary using command:

```sh
go build -linkshared test.go
```

Load plugin with test binary:

```sh
export LD_PRELOAD=./eng.so; ./test
```

plugin addresses will load into `firstmoduledata` structure of go runtime.

Created another go binary using command:

```sh
go build test.go
```

load plugin with test binary:

```sh
export LD_PRELOAD=./eng.so; ./test
```

plugin addresses will not load into `firstmoduledata`. This is because `addmoduledata()` is not called.

Is it possible to load plugin address for this case?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does LD_PRELOAD have to do with the go plugin? Go does not use the system C linker

Comment: Due to different go versions I can't use a plugin using plugin.open method. But I can use the functions of a plugin using LD_PRELOAD with binary. Because plugin will load into the address space of binary so I can access any function from that address space.  Here the problem is plugin addresses are added into firstmoduledata of a go binary compiled with linkshared option but does not for a go binary compiled without linkshared.

Comment: When a module is first loaded by the dynamic linker, an .init_array
function is invoked.  Why it's invoked for go build with linkshared and why not without linkshared? Cant I invoke it wothout linkshared?

Comment: how a plugin is loaded into go binary? Go uses dlopen to load the plugin but how it loads the addresses of plugin into go runtime? Can someone suggest?